# Android: Showing Graphics and Video Stream together

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am writing an android program in which I built a box using opengl es. Now I am writing the code to get video stream from android camera. I want to show the video stream and the box built in opengl same time on the screen. I don't know how to do it. can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a canvas drawing on two separate layers, one layer for the video stream, the other for the opengl box. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html